# Sending most recently created file via Email

Tags: bash, shell-script, email, time, mutt

I'm trying to send a log file every 24 hours or so via email. Currently I am using mutt for this. You can call mutt like this:

```
mutt -s "Log" -a file_attachment example@example.com
```

I know I can list the most recently created files using find and mtime but I want to be able to define a bash function that will find the most recently created file in a directory and then send it as an email attachment.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
mutt -s "Log" -a /path/to/*.log(.om[1]) example@example.com
```

That uses `zsh` [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). While other shell globs can only generate filenames based on their name, in `zsh`, you can use those qualifiers (`(.om[1])` above), to select based on file attributes (type, size, times, permissions...) or other criteria of your own, affect the order, apply various transformations, or select a range.

In this case  we use these qualifiers:

- `.`: select only regular files.
- `om`: order by modification time (newest first)
- `[1]`: select only the first one.

Note that if there are no `log` files in `/path/to`, the glob will fail and the command will be aborted (as you'd expect, but other shells work differently).

GNUly, the equivalent would be something like:

```
latest=$(
  find /path/to -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' -printf '%T@:%p\0' |
    sort -rzg | sed -z 's/^[^:]*://;q'
)
[ -n "$latest" ] &&
  mutt -s "Log" -a "$latest" example@example.com
```

Comment: Could you please expand on `(.om[1])`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Get_Attachment_Name ()
{
   file_attachment_dir="Whatever you want your directory to be"
   file_attachment=`ls -lrt -- "$file_attachment_dir" | grep -v "^[bcdl]"| tail -n 1 | awk '{print $9}'`
}
```

Grepping out any output lines starting with b, c, d, or l will eliminate trying to send block special files, character special files, directories or symbolic links.

`man ls` to see other file types that you may wish to exclude from your output.

Comment: Why not include only regular files `grep '^-'` instead of excluding the ones you don't want?

Comment: Note that it assumes file and user names don't contain newline or blank characters (and symlink targets don't contain newline characters). Using the `-n` option to `ls` to list users with their uid would improve matters slightly. You may want to fix the locale to `C` to make sure the date field always has 3 fields as well.